# CORS issue in Angular while hitting Algolia Browse API on staging server after deployment

Tags: angular, heroku, algolia

Few days ago I faced this problem on my localhost and I fixed it with **proxy.conf.json**.

**proxy.config.json:**

```
{
    "/1/indexes": {
    "target": "https://{{myApplicationID}}-dsn.algolia.net",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

in my **service.ts:**

```
const url: any = `/1/indexes/Product/browse?page=0&hitsPerPage=20`;
this.httpClient.get(url,{
      headers: {
        'X-Algolia-Api-Key': `${this.algoliaApplicationKeyForBrowse}`,
        'X-Algolia-Application-Id': `${this.algoliaApplicationID}`,
      },
    });
```

It worked fine on localhost.

But now the problem is, I have deployed this application to a staging server on **Heroku** and this proxy is not working there.

**/1/indexes/Product/browse?page=0&hitsPerPage=20** return the homepage of my application instead of hitting **Algolia** server.

Is there any way I can use same **proxy.conf.json** after my application is build and deployed on **Heroku**?

I tried to add **proxy.conf.json** in **angular.json** under **build** but I was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Heroku, you cannot use the proxy.conf.json approach for proxying requests to Algolia or any other external API. The `proxy.conf.json` is only meant for local development with ng serve.

To make it work on Heroku, you need to set up a proxy on your backend server (running on Heroku). The backend server will forward the requests to Algolia with the necessary headers and then return the response to your Angular app.

Here's a simple overview of the steps:

1. Set up a backend server (e.g., Node.js with Express) on Heroku.
2. Create a route on the backend server to handle proxying requests to Algolia.
3. Update your Angular service to make requests to the backend server's proxy route instead of directly to Algolia.
4. The backend server will handle the proxying and forward the requests to Algolia, adding the required headers.
5. Algolia's response will be sent back to your Angular app via the backend server.

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

// Define a route to handle proxying requests to Algolia
app.get('/api/proxy/algolia/browse', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const algoliaUrl = `https://${process.env.ALGOLIA_APPLICATION_ID}-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/Product/browse`;
    const response = await axios.get(algoliaUrl, {
      headers: {
        'X-Algolia-Api-Key': process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY,
        'X-Algolia-Application-Id': process.env.ALGOLIA_APPLICATION_ID,
      },
    });

    res.send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.response ? error.response.status : 500).send(error.message);
  }
});

// Other routes and server configurations...

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Angular Service (api.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchDataFromAlgolia() {
    // Update the URL to target your backend server's proxy route
    const url = '/api/proxy/algolia/browse?page=0&hitsPerPage=20';

    // Make the HTTP request to your backend server
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

Angular Component (dashboard.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  fetchAlgoliaData() {
    this.apiService.fetchDataFromAlgolia().subscribe((data) => {
      // Handle the response data from Algolia here
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Please note that this is a simplified example, and the actual implementation will depend on your backend server technology and setup. Make sure to configure environment variables `(e.g., ALGOLIA_API_KEY and ALGOLIA_APPLICATION_ID)` on your Heroku server to keep sensitive data secure.

This way, you can securely proxy requests to Algolia on Heroku without relying on `proxy.conf.json`